# Git: I don't understand how a pull-request can possibly work like THIS

Tags: git, pull-request

I would like to understand, how to do Git Pull Requests from the command line. I found a documentation about this here: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull - have a look at the *EXAMPLE* section). If I want to apply this concept, I think I would have to do our process works like this:

```
# Never work directly on 'master', unless we have trivial changes.
# Create privat branch instead. 
git checkout -b mybranch
# hack hack hack
git add .
git commit -m ...
git checkout master
# For the safe side (in case someone else has pushed meanwhile):
git pull
# Record the SHA from this
last_commit=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
git merge mybranch
# Now following the Example at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull 
git push # <------------------- Here be dragons!!!!
git pull-request $last_commit https://my.repository.url/blabla master
```

In this example, I find the placement of the *push* weird. The whole point of a pull-request, as I understood it, is, that only those changes go into master, which are "approved" (i.e. don't go into origin/master automatically). However, when I do the push, they are immediately visible in the most recent version of the master.

Maybe someone can enlighten me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In http://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull the first `push` is pushing from your local computer (e.g., your laptop) that *only you* have *any* access to, to your personal repository on a sharing site.  The sharing-site version allows other people to read it, but first you must write it there, with a `push` step.

Once the `push` to your "visible", sharing-site, repository finishes, you can send off a pull request to (the people managing) yet a third repository, and then they can obtain the commit(s) from your visible repository.  Your "work" repository on your laptop remains invisible to the outside world, so they would not be able to obtain your commits if you kept them only on your laptop.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, but I don't understand, how I can have a "personal repository" on the sharing site. Until now, we didn't work with "pull requests", and we just did a "push", and then, the data was accessible to everyone, and whenever someone did a "pull", he got my changes. Do I have to change something in the git server to make pull-requests work?

Comment: As for "how can I have a personal repository on a sharing site", it's easy: *you* get a repo, and *he* gets a repo, and *she* gets one: *everyone* gets one.  When everyone has one, nobody is special, they just all have one.  That's a peer-to-peer sharing system, which is how git works; making a centralized server (one that everyone pushes to) also works, but is actually a bit of a perversion of the peer-to-peer notion.  As for "do I have to change something in the git server": no, and you don't even have to use real peer-to-peer either, you can build a pull system on a centralized server.

Comment: makes no sense. If I merge and push to master it is guaranteed anyone else pulling from master will see the result of that merge.  Something is wrong here.

Comment: @SamanthaAtkins: it's important to enumerate (a) all the repositories in use; (b) all the *commits* found at those repositories; and (c) the steps you're using in *your* repository when talking to the (perhaps multiple and different) other repositories. Each repository is independent. Every Git has *its own* set of branch names; your `master` need not represent the same commit as someone else's `master`.

Comment: In particular, the work-flow that user1934428 was asking about, as shown in [the `git request-pull` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull), is one that is used when there is no central repository that you and the 400 other people all agree is "the main repository". There's no place you can point to and say *that one is right, the rest of you must use that one*. This model doesn't work well in many practical cases. If it doesn't work for you, don't use it: pick a central repository and say *that one is the right one* and use that.

Comment: I get it. It depends on forks.  DUH.